# NextJS MDX Blog - take slug from front matter in getStaticPath - how to get getStaticProps to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, markdown

This is perhaps my first actual project on NextJS. I am trying to build a blog that supports MDX. For that I am using dynamic routing. The slug is being fetched from the front matter of the markdown file. Here is my [slug].tsx file:

```
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import { sync } from "glob";

const PostPage = ({ frontMatter: { title, date }, mdxSource }: any): any => {
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto w-[50vw] mt-10">
      <div className="prose-xl">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <MDXRemote {...mdxSource} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const postsPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "posts");

const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const files = sync(`${postsPath}/**/*.mdx`);

  const paths = files.map((file) => {
    const markdownWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf-8");

    const { data: frontMatter } = matter(markdownWithMeta);

    return {
      params: {
        slug: frontMatter.slug,
      },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { slug } }: any) => {
  const markdownWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join("posts", "#1/Hello.mdx"),
    "utf-8"
  );

  const { data: frontMatter, content } = matter(markdownWithMeta);
  const mdxSource = await serialize(content);

  return {
    props: {
      frontMatter,
      slug,
      mdxSource,
    },
  };
};

export { getStaticProps, getStaticPaths };
export default PostPage;
```

As you can see, in the above code I am using getStaticPaths to get the slug from front matter. That much is working fine.

However, in getStaticProps, I am using hard coded value to one of my test mdx files. From the documentation, I read that getStaticProps runs for each paths that is returned from the getStaticPaths method.

So in each instance, I need to pass the exact file name to get markdownWithMeta. All examples in the internet I run into uses file name as slug. In that case, it is easy to just use the slug to create the path and pass it to `fs.readFileSync` in getStaticProps .

But I don't want to use my file name as slug. Is there anyway I can make this work?

The above code is so far working fine but just rendering "Hello.mdx" to all the paths

Comment: why you don't want to use filename as a slug? I think it's the best solution for this case?

Comment: @mocherfaoui It is the obvious/simple solution. I have 7+ articles on setting up MDX blog using Next.JS and all of them in one way or other end up using file name as slug.

My problem is rather that of organisation. I wanted to keep the blog posts as index.mdx inside a folder where its components/images or anything else can stay.

The folder will be just the post number. I had used slug from file name in a Gatsby blog I own and it became a bit hard to organise the posts eventually.